# Backslash or forwardslash with login id is preventing successful data fetching in php?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have student table which has student login information like id number , pincode and their detail.

The students id is like: **0123/08** pincode is: **1234**

**The working condition:**
For example when the student is login without slash 0134 and pincode, then the data is fetched successfully.Which means when **0134** id is available.
[image]
**The problem:**
when the student is login with backslash and existing id 0123/08 and pincode, then the student can log but the data is not fetched. 
[image]
can any one solve the problem:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <style type="text/css">
h3{font-family: Calibri; font-size: 22pt; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold; color:SlateBlue;
text-align: center; text-decoration: underline }
table{font-family: Calibri; color:white; font-size: 11pt; font-style: normal;
text-align:; background-color: Silver; border-collapse: collapse; 
border: 2px solid navy;     float: left;
  margin-left: 25%; 
  margin: 10%; }
table.inner{border: 0px}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<?php
include("db.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //Start session 

    //Include database connection details
    require_once('db.php');

    //Array to store validation errors
    $errmsg_arr = array();

    //Validation error flag
    $errflag = false;

    //Connect to mysql server
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    if(!$link) {
        die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    //Select database
//  $db = mysql_select_db("cbe");
    //if(!$db) {
//      die("Unable to select database");
//  }

    //Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
    function clean($str) {
        $str = @trim($str);
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $str = stripslashes($str);
        }
        return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
    }

    //Sanitize the POST values
    $login = clean($_POST['student_id']);
    $password = clean($_POST['pincode']);

    //Input Validations
    if($login == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Login ID missing';
        $errflag = true;
    }
    if($password == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Password missing';
        $errflag = true;
    }

    //If there are input validations, redirect back to the login form
    //if($errflag) {
    //  $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    //  session_write_close();
    //  header("location: login.php");
    //  exit();
    //}

    //Create query
    $qry="SELECT * FROM student WHERE stud_id='$login' AND stud_pincode='$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db,$qry)  or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($db));
        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);


        if(is_array($row) && !empty($row)) {        
            $_SESSION['name'] = $row['stud_fname'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['stud_id'];
            echo $row['stud_id'];

            $_SESSION['favcolor'] = 'green';
            $_SESSION['animal']   = 'cat';
            $_SESSION['time']     = time();
            header("location: index.php");
            exit();
        }else {
            echo "Invalid username or password.";
            echo "<br/>";
            echo "<a href='login.php'>Go back</a>";
        }

        if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
            header('Location: index.php');          
        }
    }  

    else {
?>
    <p><font size="+2">Login</font></p>
    <form name="form1" method="POST" action="">
        <table width="75%" border="0">
            <tr> 
                <td width="15%">ID Number:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="student_id" ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td width="15%">Student PIN:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="pincode"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>

                <td>&nbsp;</td>

            </tr>
            <tr><td>Not registered? </td>
            <td><a href=/cbe/RegisterStudent.html>Reister Now!</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

specially this things from above code will have any problem?

```
 //Sanitize the POST values
    $login = clean($_POST['student_id']);
    $password = clean($_POST['pincode']);

$qry="SELECT * FROM student WHERE stud_id='$login' AND stud_pincode='$password'";
        $result = mysqli_query($db,$qry)  or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($db));
            $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);


            if(is_array($row) && !empty($row)) {        
                $_SESSION['name'] = $row['stud_fname'];
                $_SESSION['id'] = $row['stud_id'];
                echo $row['stud_id'];                    

                header("location: index.php");
                exit();
            }
```

The php file which fetches the data:

```
    <?php


        $query = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE stud_id=".$_SESSION['id']." ORDER BY id DESC";

if ($result = $db->query($query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["stud_fname"], $row["stud_lname"]);
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>". $row['stud_id']."</td>";
            echo "<td>". $row['stud_fname']."</td>";
            echo "<td>". $row['stud_lname']."</td>";    
            echo "<td>". $row['stud_gfname']."</td>";
            echo "<td>". $row['stud_gender']."</td>";
            echo "<td>". $row['stud_dep']."</td>";  
            echo "<td><a href=\"edit.php?id= $row[id]\">Edit</a> </td>";

            //Delete Code: <a href=\"delete.php?id= $row[id]\" onClick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')\">Delete</a>
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->free();
}

        ?>
```

Comment: It is unclear where exactly you are using that ID - can you clarify?

Comment: 1. you need to properly escape data you get from a client, since you cannot trust such data. It may break your queries as it does in this case. Take a look at "prepared statements" and "parameter binding" in the `mysqli` documentation to learn how to do that. There is no way around that, your code is vulnerable otherwise and may expose private data.

Comment: 2. you should _never_ store a password in a database. Period. Nothing to discuss here. What you should store is a _hash_ of passwords. Then, at login time, you compare a hash of the password provided with the hash stored inside the database. That way no passwords are exposed even if your site gets hacked. There are many examples for that out on the internet. Again, this is not optional. What you currently do is not acceptable.

Comment: @arkascha he appears to be protecting his queries adequately though. The notion that any code that doesn't use prepared statements is inherently vulnerable is incorrect, although it's always preferable to use them.

Comment: @Pekka웃 S Sorry, maybe I got something wrong, but when looking over that wall of code I had the impression it is vulnerable. I may be wrong though, sure.

Comment: Thanks @ Pekka for advice

Comment: @arkascha argh, you still have a point - it's the sanitation function that is causing the OP's problem. :) (and +1 for the password advice, of course)

Comment: @Pekka웃    Indeed, that self crafted `clean()` function does more harm than it does help...

Comment: @ arkascha +1  for best password storing tech

Answer (score 0):

Your `clean()` function is using `stripslashes()` which - as the name of the function says - strips slashes from your input data, leading to `0123/08` becoming `012308` in the internal comparison.

For a quick fix, remove the `stripslashes()` call; it serves to purpose anyway. You could arguably get rid of the entire `clean()` function and just use `mysql_real_escape_string()` instead.

For a proper fix, consider using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), an approach to safely handling incoming data that makes it much more difficult to screw things up.